# How do I find all file path apart from specific one?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have list of files in filename.txt

```
dir /etc/folder1
dir /usr/folder2
```

I need to check if there is any other directory entry in file apart from dir /usr/folder2 ?
Basically, make sure there are no other entries apart from dir /usr/folder2, I tried using
but this even matches dir /usr/folder2

```
 grep -E 'dir /[:alpha]*/*' /etc/filename.txt
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to supply a regular expression, just pass the `-v` (inverse) flag

```
grep -v 'dir /usr/folder2' filename.txt
```

Comment: What if I want to list only those files starting with dir other than 'dir /usr/folder2' ?

Comment: @1_CR not really, it will also print lines that look like ``file /usr/fold/myfile``

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko, you are right, I misinterpreted the OP's question

Answer (score 1):

That's what you want:

```
grep -P '^dir (?!/usr/folder2$)' filename.txt
```

This will print all lines that start with `dir` folowed with anything except your specified folder.

If you just want to see if there are any other `dir`s (without printing them) use this:

```
grep -qP -m 1 '^dir (?!/usr/folder2$)' filename.txt && echo 'There are other dirs' || echo 'There are no other dirs'
```

In this case you don't need the output, so `-q` was used. Also remember to use `-m 1` to stop reading the file if at least one match was found.

Comment: The first is even pulling text which has dir name in its line e.g from comment

Comment: @ajayramesh what do you mean? Do you want to remove ``dir`` word from the beginning? Try ``grep -P 'dir (?!/usr/folder2)' filename.txt | cut -d' ' -f2-``

Comment: What I mean is the command is pulling all sentences from file which contain 'dir', like even if comment has 'dir' it is pulling that comment. I need only dir with path ( 'dir /usr/folder')

Comment: @ajayramesh but I gave you the solution in previous comment

Comment: I am sorry if I am not explaining correctly, what I am saying is if there is a comment "yada yada yada dir yada yada'  then the command will also print the comment and the dir path like
yada yada yada dir yada yada
dir /etc/folder1

Comment: @ajayramesh oh, that's right! My bad, sorry. I have edited my answer. That's easy to solve by adding ``^`` to match the start of the line and ``$`` to match the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1=="dir" && $2!="/usr/folder2" {print}' filename.txt
```

or

```
grep ^dir filename.txt | grep -v /usr/folder2
```